# Shadow removal from color image

Tags: c++, opencv

I tried to remove shadow from that image: [container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF5Jo.jpg)
According to some answers from the site, but without success.
I try to remove shadow and read the container number (need to be readable),
that not the only image, i try on several of images.
this is my code until now:

```
Mat imgSrc, imgDst, imgResult , mblured, step3, diff_img, norm_img, threshold_img;
src = imread("Test7.jpg");
int nChannels = imgSrc.channels();
vector<Mat> channels(nChannels);
vector<Mat> result;

createTrackbar("Element:\n 0: Rect \n 1: Cross \n 2: Ellipse", "Dilation Demo",
    &dilation_elem, max_elem,
    Dilation);
createTrackbar("Kernel size:\n 2n +1", "Dilation Demo",
    &dilation_size, max_kernel_size,
    Dilation);

split(src, channels);

namedWindow("channels[0]");
imshow("channels[0]", channels[0]);

int dilation_type = 0;
if (dilation_elem == 0) { dilation_type = MORPH_RECT; }
else if (dilation_elem == 1) { dilation_type = MORPH_CROSS; }
else if (dilation_elem == 2) { dilation_type = MORPH_ELLIPSE; }
Mat element = getStructuringElement(dilation_type,
    Size(2 * dilation_size + 1, 2 * dilation_size + 1),
    Point(dilation_size, dilation_size));

dilate(channels[0], dilation_dst, element);

medianBlur(dilation_dst, mblured, 61);  

absdiff(channels[0], mblured, step3);

diff_img = 255 - step3;
norm_img = diff_img.clone();

normalize(diff_img, norm_img, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC1); //NORM_MINMAX

result.push_back(norm_img);

dilate(channels[1], dilation_dst, element);

medianBlur(dilation_dst, mblured, 61);
absdiff(channels[1], mblured, step3);

diff_img = 255 - step3;
norm_img = diff_img.clone();

normalize(diff_img, norm_img, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC1);

result.push_back(norm_img);

dilate(channels[2], dilation_dst, element);

medianBlur(dilation_dst, mblured, 61);
absdiff(channels[2], mblured, step3);

diff_img = 255 - step3;
norm_img = diff_img.clone();

normalize(diff_img, norm_img, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC1);

result.push_back(norm_img);

merge(result, imgResult);

namedWindow("second_normalize");
imshow("second_normalize", imgResult);
```

got this result: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QECTU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

@shaykoo

maybe you can search for finlayson  + shadow removal. It talked about shadow removal. The idea is all colour of same tone regardless of illumnicity can collapse into a chroma line (i couldnt really recall the exact details). The simple implementation will require you to let the image go through some PCA operation.

I think there might be  some C++ implementation lurking somewhere in the net

Comment: Thanks, I read finlayson paper and do not understand so much how to implement it, I'm not from the field of image processing.